# create a new dataframe from an aggregated dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has aggregated people by location like so

```
location_id | score | number_of_males | number_of_females
     1      |  20   |        2        |         1
     2      |  45   |        1        |         2
```

I want to create a new dataframe that unaggregated this one so I get something like

```
location_id | score | number_of_males | number_of_females
     1      |  20   |        1        |         0
     1      |  20   |        1        |         0
     1      |  20   |        0        |         1
     2      |  45   |        1        |         0
     2      |  45   |        0        |         1
     2      |  45   |        0        |         0
```

Or even better

```
location_id | score |       sex 
     1      |  20   |       male       
     1      |  20   |       male    
     1      |  20   |       female
     2      |  45   |       male
     2      |  45   |       female
     2      |  45   |       female
```

I want to do something like

```
import pandas as pd
aggregated_df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(SOME_PATH)
unaggregated_df = df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['location_id', 'score', 'sex'])

for row in aggregated_df:
  for column in ['number_of_males', 'number_of_females']:
    for number_of_people in range(0, row[column]):
      if column == 'number_of_males':
        sex = 'male'
      else:
        sex = 'female'
      unaggregated_df.append([{'location_id': row['location_id'],
                              'score': row['score'],
                              'sex': sex}],
                             ignore_index=True)
```

I am having trouble getting the dict to append even though this seems to be supported in [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#appending-rows-to-a-dataframe)

Is there a more pandthonic (panda's version of pythonic) way to accomplish this?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Sorry I have been traveling and haven't had a chance to test.  I have not forgotten :)  Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Comment: No worries, there is no fire :) test and accept/reject the solution !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to get your result using `group_by`:

```
ids = ['location_id','score']

def foo(d):
    return pd.Series(d['number_of_males'].values*['male'] + 
                     d['number_of_females'].values*['female'])

pd.melt(df.groupby(ids).apply(foo).reset_index(), id_vars=ids).drop('variable', 1)

#Out[13]:
#   location_id  score   value
#0            1     20    male
#1            2     45    male
#2            1     20    male
#3            2     45  female
#4            1     20  female
#5            2     45  female
```

Comment: I ended up using a subset of this on my real data set.  
df.groupby(ids).apply(foo).reset_index(), dropping the junk column and renaming the last column.  Yours worked on the toy data, but not my real data for somereason.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Leaving this comment for posterity for anyone else (or future me).

Comment: Multiplying an array of numbers times a list with a string it now gives me the error ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S21') dtype('S21') dtype('S21').  To fix this I updated the expand function to have a gross triple for loop: def expand_students(d):
    list_student_rows = []
    for group_label, student_label in zip(group_labels, student_labels):
        for value in d[group_label].values:
            for x in range(0, value):
                list_student_rows.extend([student_label])
    return pd.Series(list_student_rows)

Answer (score 0):

Until this I could do in a pandas functions

```
print df
location_id  score  number_of_males  number_of_females
     1        20           2                 1
     2        45           1                 2
```

Converting the two columns to one,

```
df.set_index(['location_id','score']).stack().reset_index()
Out[102]: 
   location_id  score            level_2  0
0            1     20    number_of_males  2
1            1     20  number_of_females  1
2            2     45    number_of_males  1
3            2     45  number_of_females  2
```

But then I have to iterate to increase the number of rows using python loop :(